# Stop application from installing or interrupt application during the installation

Tags: blackberry

i want to stop the installation of application on my blackberry device. 
Is there is any way to get notify during the installation of application or any way to interrupt the installation of application.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are on a BES, or have authorized an application to manage code modules (pre OS 4.6) or application management (OS 4.6 or greater), there is no way for an application to be installed without the user's knowledge and acceptance.

However there is an API (CodeModuleListener) which can be notified when modules are added or deleted. An application with such a listener could then notify the user who could take appropriate action.

Comment: thanks Richar.......Is it notify before any third party application is installed.

Comment: @ms It will notify whenever new module "is being" installed.

Comment: I hate to be pedantic, but the OS will be so: The API documentation for CodeModuleListener.modulesAdded() says "The callback made when new code modules have been added to the system." Past tense, so after the modules have been added. Any object that registers to receive the callback should have this method called.

Comment: Thanks Richard....... but the CodeModuleListener is available from the 5.0 OS....but i want something for 4.5 OS. Is something available for that..